Do non-uniform distributions produce inconsistent models?
This is sort of two questions in one, but the first one is really just something I'd like to confirm as being the case from which I think the second one follows. My motivation is that I've been looking for some objective justification for preferring the uniform distribution when the actual distribution is not known.
The first question is, I think that if we have 2 variables that we don't know whether they're independent or not, it's best to model them as independent since this model will include the possibility of them being dependent. I haven't found any proof so I may be wrong but it seems clear in the cases of coins. If 2 coins are 100% correlated, the independent model will include all possible combinations, not just the ones where they're dependent, but not the other way around: if I model them as dependent, my model won't include the possibility of them being independent. I think that for continuos variables something similar will happen but in a probabilistic way. Is there any known rule or theorem about this? Or is this rule just wrong?
Assuming the rule above is correct, that means if we have two variables that are 100% correlated but don't know it yet, we can, and should model them as independent, and after doing some experiments we should be able to see their dependency, something like a coin and a mirror that we don't know whether is the same coin or not.
But if I combine this with having non-uniform distribution, for instance if I assign $P(H) = \frac{1}{3}$ and $P(T) = \frac{2}{3}$, then my model will actually have a different bias than the one I originally introduced, since the two impossible combinations will really have probability $0$, $P(H)$ will be a square of side $\frac{1}{3}$ with area of $\frac{1}{9}$ and $P(T)$ will have area $\frac{4}{9}$. So whatever bias I had first, even if it was justified, has turned into a new more extreme bias without any empirical data making its way into the model. So the problem I want to point out is not the original bias but the self-inconsistency of the model. And it gets worse the more "copies" of the same variable there are.
So I just wonder if this observation is correct and whether this has a name or some more general form, for instance for continuous variables?

I am not clear what you are claiming.  You start with $P(H,H)+P(H,T)+P(T,H)+P(T,T)=1$ since these are probabilities.  Assuming independence creates a further constraint $P(H,H)=\big(P(H,H)+P(H,T)\big)\big(P(H,H)+P(T,H)\big)$ - and this then implies three others - which would not be able to model well your example with two coins "that are $100%$ correlated".

Not am I clear about what a "uniform distribution" would mean here.  Is it the prior for a Bayesian analysis?

@Henry I'm just picturing it in general as a $N \times N$ grid where $N=2$ for coins. If you run tests, you'll conditionalize on the observation that the cases where $N_1\ne N_2$ never happen and get closer and closer to a diagonal line, but if the model doesn't include for instance $H_1,T_2$ as an option then you'll never be able to model them as independent in case they are.

By uniform distribution I just mean assigning equal probabilities to all possible cases. I understand preferring the uniform distribution as a more technical way of stating the principle of indifference but I may be completely wrong here. So in this specific case I just mean assigning 1/2 to coin results when we know nothing about whether it's biased or not, instead starting with some other probabilities.

To be clear, when I say you'll never be able to model two dependent variables as independent I mean as long as you don't use a new model. I'm understanding conditionalization as just keeping the same model but "discarding" some possible cases in the model.
